# Best way to add a list of tags to a UITableViewCell xib that's using autolayout

Tags: ios, list, uitableview, tags, autolayout

I'm trying to add a list of tags (strings with boxes/borders around them) to UITableViewCell xib that's using autolayout. I'm not sure the best way to approach this. Any tips? Below is a mockup of what I'm trying to make.

[image]

Comment: It isn't t all clear what you are asking. What do you mean "add a list of tags to a UITableViewCell xib?" By tags you don't mean the UIView integer tag property, do you? You mean strings with boxes around them, like SO tags?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'll update the post - I mean a list of strings with a box around them.

Comment: Ok, so you need to write code that lays out your labels. Putting the boxes around them is easy by setting the layer properties (borderWidth, borderColor, and cornerRadius.) Laying out the labels will mean writing a bunch of code that generates labels that are sized to fit their text and has constraints to space them evenly. I'm not going to do that work for you though.

Answer (score 0):

i think to approach the mockup using autolayout is not the best way,i suggest use code create view,and set view's frame